# Aligning an unknown number of divs with different heights

Tags: css

I am creating a webpage where users can create different ticket types for an event.

I don't know how many tickets a user wishes to create so I can't use CSS Grid for layout.

Instead I have used inline block.

Depending on the ticket options a user selects, the height of the container (className = createTicket) increases.

When this happens the height of all containers with className = createTicket is increasing but they are no longer aligned and I don't understand why.

When I set them to have the same height, they still aren't aligned. The ticket with more elements is up towards the top of the page and the others are further down the page.

Ideally, I want each ticket to be the same size and align to the same position.

A simplification of the html is below.

If a user selects 'specific' in the second input, another input will appear for that container.

:

```
<div className="wrapper">
        
        {this.state.tickets.map((e, i) => {
            return (

                <div className ="content createTicket" id={`ticket${i}`} >

                    <form key={i}>

                        <div className="group">
                            <input
                                required
                                type="text"
                                value={this.state.tickets[i].ticketType}
                                onChange={event => this.changeTicketDetails(event, 'ticketType', i)}
                                placeholder="Ticket Name eg. General Admission"
                            />     
                        </div>

                        
                        <div className="group">
                            <select
                                required 
                                value={this.state.tickets[i].stopSelling}
                                onChange={event => this.changeSellingTimes(event, i, 'stopSelling', 'stopSellingTime', values)}
                            >
                                <option value='' disabled>Stop Selling Tickets</option>
                                <option value="eventBegins">When Event Begins</option>
                                <option value="eventEnds">When Event Ends</option>
                                <option value="specific">At Specific Date and Time</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>


                        {this.state.tickets[i].stopSelling == 'specific'  ?
                            <div>
                                <div className="group datePickerDiv"
                                >  
                                        <DatePicker
                                            className="datePicker"
                                            timeIntervals={15}
                                            onChange={event => this.setSpecificTime(event, i, 'stopSellingTime', values)}
                                            selected={this.state.tickets[i].stopSellingTime}
                                            placeholderText='Select Date And Time'
                                            showTimeSelect
                                            dateFormat="Pp"
                                            required
                                        />

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            : <div className = "group"></div>
                        }

                        {this.state.tickets.length > 1 &&
                            <button
                                className = "secondary" 
                                onClick={event => this.deleteTicket(event, i) }>Delete Ticket
                            </button>
                        }

                    </form>

                </div>
            )
        })}
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
.content {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    position: relative;
}


.wrapper {
    text-align: center;


}

.wrapper > .content {
    position: relative;
    padding: 3.5%;
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    border-radius: 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 2%;
}

.wrapper > .content + .content {
    margin-top: 0%;
}
```

[image: print screen of problem]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use flexbox in this case.

Change your .wrapper to

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

and your .wrapper > .content remove `display: inline-block`